# Is there any method in Elastic Search to get result in case of misspelling?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to know if it's possible to search among the data in case of misspelling like we search in google.
Currently this query returns thousands of results:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "obama"
    }
  }
}
```

but when I change it to:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "omama"
    }
  }
}
```

"obama" replaced with "omama" there is no result. is it possible to get results in case of wrong spelling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [Fuzzy Query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html) .

```
{
   "query": {
       "fuzzy": {
            "field_name" : "omama" 
       }
   }
}
```

If you are run this on single field the you can use [fuzzy query like this field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-flt-field-query.html#query-dsl-flt-field-query)

```
{
    "fuzzy_like_this_field" : {
        "name.first" : {
            "like_text" : "omama",
            "max_query_terms" : 12
        }
    }
}
```

You can also check [Phonetic Matching](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/phonetic-matching.html)

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-analysis-phonetic

Comment: thanks for your reply but this query returns 0 results. what to do now?

Comment: Update my answer.Please check now

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a `fuzzy` query, ([documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html#query-dsl-fuzzy-query)) :

```
{
  "query": {
    "fuzzy": {
      "name": "omama"
    }
  }
}
```

You should get your result :

```
{
   "took": 12,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 2.7917595,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "obama",
            "_id": "D_ovfcHkQwODdftWM4_z1Q",
            "_score": 2.7917595,
            "_source": {
               "name": "obama"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```